# Usage of the expression "go they went"

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, expressions

I noticed the usage of *go they went* in the TV show *How I Met Your Mother*:

> Marshall: Where are all my underpants?
>
> Lily: Did you check your suitcase?
>
> (Marshall checks his suitcase, gives a thumbs-up)
>
> Marshall: Let's go.
>
> Future Ted VO: And **go they went**, all the way to St. Cloud, Minnesota, Marshall's hometown.

Is using this expression correct?

Comment: Apparently a funny twist to 'and **so** they went.'

Comment: It's often more helpful to ask not 'is it correct?' but 'does it work?'

Comment: I have a nagging feeling that I know this phrase from somewhere.  Possibly I'm just misremembering some e.e.cummings.

Comment: @Kris, funny, I read it as a funny twist on, "and *go* they did." I'm making up my own preamble here:  *After many months of deliberation they finally decided to go*.  *And* **go** *they did! all the way to St. Cloud, Minnesota.*   So swap out 'did' for 'went'

Comment: @Jim: I have a feeling that the preceding line(s) of the script would provide context that would make this seemingly awkward structure seem much less out-of-place. I'm surprised the O.P. didn't give us the benefit of seeing whatever those lines were; I'm almost certain they're the key to this puzzle. It wouldn't be unlike someone reading your comment, and saying, "_I'm making up my own preamble here_ – is it normal for writers to make up their own preambles?" without providing any additional context.

Comment: If this is actually what they said, sounds similar to the structure of "...and eat they did!"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to stress the verb in this way you should use do/did, so the correct  expression would have been "And go they did."  "Went" would have been correct if it had been preceded only by an adverb in Future Ted VO's comment.  For example, if Marshall had said "Let's get away" then Future Ted VO could have correctly said "And away they went."

Actually I think "And go they went" sounds so obviously wrong that it's deliberately being used to sound amusing.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, it is not grammatical.

In that context, you would use "and so they went".